# Run on spark a weka Classification Algorithm

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata

As I checked the Spark MLib, there are limited classification algorithms included.
Is it possible to add Weka jar file to the spark and use its classification algorithms on Spark workers.
I know there is not any parallelization benefit with doing this job, but I am curious to know if I could do so.

Answer (score 0):

HamidReza,

You cannot really use directly weka jars to distribute your learning algorithms. Their implementations are not compatible with distributed systems.

Nevertheless, there exists a specific project named distributedWekaSparkDev but I haven't tried it yet.

You can learn more about it here : http://markahall.blogspot.com/2017/07/integrating-spark-mllib-into-weka.html